# Export data from Microsoft Access (VBA) using recordset without making it append to previous documents

Tags: vba, excel, ms-access

I am working on a group project at school and need to be able to export data from an Access table to an excel document that is formatted with specific headings (for Sage import). I am having trouble with the "exportItems" function.

Everytime I run my code, it will create duplicate rows in excel. For example: On export, it exports 1 item that a customer ordered. If I export it again to a different file name and location, that item will be duplicated and the excel document contains 2 instances. It then becomes 3, and then 4, if I repeat those steps.

Any help would be appreciated. I feel like it is an error somewhere in my SQL Insert Statement.

```
Private Sub cmdConfirmExport_Click()


If Not IsNull(txtInputFile.Value) Or txtInputFile.Value = "" Then
    Dim exportID As Integer
    Dim insertOESQL, insertOEDSQL, FileName, DeleteSQL, nameInput, rsSQL As String
    exportID = Form_QuoteDetail.QuotesID
    nameInput = txtInputFile.Value

    exportOrders (exportID)

    ' To insert the order details and be able to get the line number,
    ' create a function similar to exportCommentsOE that will use a recordset to get the values for
    'ORDUNIQ(QuotesID FK), ITEM(Vendor Item Num), DESC(Item Description), QTYORDERED(Quantity), QTYBACKORD(Quantity),
    'UNITPRICE(Unit Price), UNITCOST(Unit Cost)
    ' Then with While (Not .EOF), Insert individual item records using rs.Fields([FieldName]). LINENUM
    ' will be added as a value from a counter that goes up by 32 until it reaches the end of the recordset.

    exportItems (exportID)
    exportCommentsOE (exportID)


    FileName = FolderSelection & "\" & "OE_" & nameInput & "_" & Format(Date, "yyyyMMdd") & ".xlsx"

    'FileName = CurrentProject.Path & "\" & "OE_" & nameInput & "_" & Format(Date, "yyyyMMdd") & ".xlsx"

    DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, "Orders", FileName, True
    DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, "Order_Details", FileName, True
    DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, "Order_Detail_Lot_Numbers", FileName, True
    DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, "Order_Detail_Serial_Numbers", FileName, True
    DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, "Order_Payment_Schedules", FileName, True
    DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, "Order_Comments_Instructions", FileName, True
    MsgBox "Export Complete", vbOKOnly, "Success"

    DeleteSQL = "DELETE * FROM Orders WHERE NOT ORDUNIQ = " & exportID

    CurrentDb.Execute DeleteSQL
    DoCmd.Close

Else
    MsgBox "You must input a file name.", vbOKOnly, "Invalid Input"
End If

End Sub



Function exportItems(itemQuoteID As Integer)
On Error GoTo exportError
Dim rsSQL, rsINSERTSQL As String
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim rslineCount As Integer
Dim rsORDUNIQ, rsQTYO, rsQTYBO As Integer
Dim rsUP, rsUC As Currency
Dim rsDesc, rsITEM, rsHC As String
Set rs = Nothing
rslineCount = 32
rsSQL = "SELECT [QuotesID FK], [Vendor Item Num], [Item Description], [Quantity], [Unit Price], [Unit Cost], [HASCOMMENT] FROM [Quote Detail]" _
        & "WHERE [QuotesID FK] = " & itemQuoteID

Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(rsSQL)

With rs
    .MoveLast
    .MoveFirst

    While (Not .EOF)
    rsORDUNIQ = .Fields("[QuotesID FK]")
    rsITEM = .Fields("[Vendor Item Num]")
    rsDesc = .Fields("[Item Description]")
    rsQTYO = .Fields("[Quantity]")
    rsQTYBO = .Fields("[Quantity]")
    rsUP = .Fields("[Unit Price]")
    rsUC = .Fields("[Unit Cost]")
    rsHC = .Fields("[HASCOMMENT]")

    rsINSERTSQL = "INSERT INTO Order_Details(ORDUNIQ, [LINENUM], [ITEM], [DESC], [QTYORDERED], [QTYBACKORD], [UNITPRICE], [UNITCOST], [COMMINST])" _
                    & "VALUES (" & rsORDUNIQ & "," & rslineCount & ", '" & rsITEM & "', '" & rsDesc & "'," & rsQTYO & "," & rsQTYBO & "," & rsUP & "," & rsUC _
                    & ", '" & rsHC & "')"
    CurrentDb.Execute rsINSERTSQL
    rslineCount = rslineCount + 32
    .MoveNext

    Wend
    .Close
End With
    Set rs = Nothing
ExitFunction:
    Set rs = Nothing
    Exit Function
exportError:
    MsgBox "An error has occured during export of items."
    Resume ExitFunction
End Function
```

Comment: on a side note `dim a,b,c as string` only makes c a string.....

Comment: Haha was hoping that was the issue, I separated the variable but same problem. Thanks for the tip though! Will keep in mind.

Comment: How do you define the connection to de DataBase? ODBC?

Comment: I'm opening a recordset using CurrentDb. I'm sorry if that doesn't make sense, because I have no idea what I'm explaining. TBH I programmed my entire life in C++ and focus on Contest Programming (CCC). Never had much experience with application development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the reason. The actual SQL Insert statement continued to create entries in the DB. This would all be exported to the Excel Spreadsheet making it look like it was "appended" to the previous document.

Solution was just to make tables (Orders would have a parallel table called Orders_Export as an example) and use it as a middle man. The INSERT Command would insert data into both tables and the export would only export data from the Orders_Export table. The Orders_Export table was then cleared but all data remained in the Orders table. This was the work around I implemented. Thanks to all that helped!